# Losing context of class when invoking method using async.queue

Tags: javascript, node.js, this, async.js

When using async.js's queue function with a class's method as the worker, the class context appears to become lost. The following code gives the value of `this` as `undefined`:

```
const { queue } = require('async');

class ClassName {
  constructor() {
    this.q = queue(this.worker);
  }

  run() {
    this.q.push();
  }

  worker() {
    console.log(this)
  }
}

const x = new ClassName()
x.run()
```

I can pass the context directly to the worker function as the payload in `push`. However, I would prefer to be able to refer to the class's context from the method itself. Can anyone help me out with this? I feel like it might just be a lack of understanding of `this` on my part.

Comment: Have a look at the duplicate. tl;dr: `queue(this.worker.bind(this));`

Comment: Thanks, that's a fantastically helpful answer in the linked question.